# Pytroch segmentation model(.pt) not converting to CoreML

Tags: python, machine-learning, coreml, faster-rcnn

According to apple article [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10154/#) we need Wrap the Model to Allow Tracing which is be followed the same.

```
class WrappedDeeplabv3Resnet1011(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WrappedDeeplabv3Resnet1011, self).__init__()
        self.model = torch.load('/content/aircraft_best_model.pt',map_location ='cpu').eval()

    def forward(self, x):
        res = self.model(x)
        # extract the tensor we want from the output dictionary
        x = res['out']
        return x
```

I see the my model doesn't have the key "Out" but I see the other keys like show below

```
[{'boxes': tensor([[ 510.2429,  229.1375, 1011.1587,  399.5730],
        [ 550.1007,  202.8524, 1047.5089,  376.9215],
        [ 457.9409,  196.4182,  947.7454,  412.4210],
        [ 333.6804,  204.8605, 1073.0546,  442.6238]],
       grad_fn=<StackBackward0>), 'labels': tensor([1, 2, 3, 1]), 'scores': tensor([0.0870, 0.0631, 0.0587, 0.0531], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)}]
```

when I apply any of these keys as output it throws the error as shown below

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

my model eval() shown like below

```
FasterRCNN(
  (transform): GeneralizedRCNNTransform(
      Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
      Resize(min_size=(800,), max_size=1333, mode='bilinear')
  )
  (backbone): BackboneWithFPN(
    (body): IntermediateLayerGetter(
      (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
      (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (layer1): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer3): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (4): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (5): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer4): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(1024, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (fpn): FeaturePyramidNetwork(
      (inner_blocks): ModuleList(
        (0): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (2): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (3): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(2048, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (layer_blocks): ModuleList(
        (0-3): 4 x Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (extra_blocks): LastLevelMaxPool()
    )
  )
  (rpn): RegionProposalNetwork(
    (anchor_generator): AnchorGenerator()
    (head): RPNHead(
      (conv): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (cls_logits): Conv2d(256, 3, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
      (bbox_pred): Conv2d(256, 12, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    )
  )
  (roi_heads): RoIHeads(
    (box_roi_pool): MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=['0', '1', '2', '3'], output_size=(7, 7), sampling_ratio=2)
    (box_head): TwoMLPHead(
      (fc6): Linear(in_features=12544, out_features=1024, bias=True)
      (fc7): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    )
    (box_predictor): FastRCNNPredictor(
      (cls_score): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=6, bias=True)
      (bbox_pred): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=24, bias=True)
    )
  )
)
```

How to convert the pytroch model to CoreML

Comment: Instead of calling `res['out']` try building a new output tensor using `res['boxes']`, `res['labels']`, and `res['scores']`. I suspect you need to have all of these in a single tensor to output.

Comment: @gnodab How? if we stack the torch i.e torch.stack(boxes, label , scores) still it will multi dimensional.

Comment: share a link to your model

Comment: @anandyn02 I would suggest using `torch.cat`. You may have to check and change dtypes on some things. But this way you're keeping the expected dims. Just extending one dim to be a bit longer to keep all the info you want.

Comment: @burglarhobbit model can be downloaded from here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qBr9_dW2XKpU6iRWIQf_OAR9nL_U0o-t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should modify your WrappedDeeplabv3Resnet1011 class to return the desired key. Based on your error message, it seems that 'boxes' might be the correct key..

Comment: @KapilaShobit if return the only score values, I miss the box's point. As output we need score & box values.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10154/?time=442) it loads a pretrained model from torch hub.

```
self.model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=True).eval()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        res = self.model(x)
        print(type(res))
        print(res.keys())
```

The pretrained model returns `collections.OrderedDict` which has keys `['out', 'aux']`. Hence it is running without any bugs. In your case, the model is loaded locally from the ".pt" file. What the model returns on passing input tensor to it depends on how the model is structured (basically the code written in the constructor, `__init__` function of your model). Your model returns a list of dictionary with keys - 'scores', 'labels' and  'boxes'. It does'nt return a dictionary but a list of dictionary. You can modify the forward function to return the desired key in dictionary from a list. If you need both boxes and scores, concatenate them as single tensor and then later split them. -

```
     def forward(self, x):
        res = self.model(x)
        # extract the tensor we want from the output dictionary
        x = torch.cat(res[0]['scores'], res[0]['boxes'], 1) 

        return x
```

This will remove the error you are getting -  "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
"

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should be able to update and say pass out: `x = torch.cat((res[0]['scores'], res[0]['labels'], res[0]['boxes']), 1)` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str", when you expect a dictionary as output, it usually means you get a list of dictionaries returned (in the context of ML models).

Quickfix: Either use the debugger from PyTorch or a print out statement to collect infos such as size, keys, type, and first element. You will probably be alright, if you change `x = res['out']` to `x = res[0]['out']`. You should have not more than one model in your list judging from your code snippet.

Comment: when I replace with res['out'] to x = res[0]['out']. Its throwing error as KeyError: 'out'

Comment: it is throwing KeyError because that keys does'nt exist in dictionary returned by your model. As mentioned in my answer below, your model only returns  a list of dictionary with keys - 'scores', 'labels' and 'boxes.

Comment: Check with res[0].keys() what keys your dictionary has. Since you get a KeyError, 'out' is currently not a key in your returned dict. You can add it with res[0]['out'] = torch.cat((res[0]['scores'], res[0]['labels'], res[0]['boxes']), 1).